# Highstock ranged overlay

Tags: highcharts

I have an Highstock graph on which I would like to add "time zones" as an overlay.

Default graph:
[image]

Expected:
[image]

Each zone would have a name, a start and an end timestamp, a background color (here with alpha) and the basic label properties.

**Is it possible with the current API ?**

I though about two ways to it:

- Using the draw API (looks like hell to know if the zone will be visible, find the pos from the timestamp, etc)
- Faking the zones with multiple area charts overlaping each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [plotBands](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.plotBands)

```
 xAxis: {        
        plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
            color: 'rgba(120,120,150,0.3)',
            from: 2,
            to: 4
        },{ // mark the weekend
            color: 'rgba(255,0,150,0.3)',
            from: 3,
            to: 5
        }]
  }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/v89Xw/